# A slight dilemma on the statement of Cartan's criteria in Lie Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Humphrey's book on Lie Algebra states the Cartan Criteria as follows:

Let $V$ be finite dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $L\subset gl(V)$ be a subalgebra. If $Tr(xy)=0$ $\forall x\in L^{'}, y\in L$. Then $L$ is solvable.

But the same criteria in Erdmann and Wildon's book is as follows:

Let $V$ be finite dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $L\subset gl(V)$ be a subalgebra. If $Tr(xy)=0$ $\forall x\in L, y\in L$. Then $L$ is solvable.

The difference is very slight in the second one $x\in L$ while in the first $x\in L^{'}$. Now obviously the second statement is assuming something more.

What I can't figure out is whether this small change makes a large difference. Or, are both the statement's same in some way!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I didn't get the meaning! What becomes false?

Comment: No see the none of the statement is wrong. It is just that the second statement assumes something more! I am not worried by the name of the criteria, but what I want know is how much difference does the two statement make.

Comment: Or in otherwords, can the first statement be derived from the second statement?

Comment: I looked it up in Erdmann's book, and it says "for all $x\in L$ and $y\in L'$", on page $80$. Can you say where exactly you have found this in the book? Cartan's first criterion is as in Humphrey's book, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion). But indeed, Cartan's criterion is and "if and only if solvable".

Comment: Yes ok !! This is the proposition before that page, that is 79 . Although it is not the Cartan Criteria that is written in the book, it is what you saw in page 80, but Humphreys says that the first statement is the cartan Criteria. If we go by Erdmann, Cartan Criteria is that "If L is any finite dimensional Lie-algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, then L is solvable iff $Tr(ad x \circ ad y)=0 \forall x\in L, y\in L^{'}$. But this precise statement is given as a corollary in Humphreys without any name, as I have already said that Humphreys assumes that the first statement is the Cartan's Critera!

Comment: What my question is Can we prove statement 1 (Humphreys), using statement 2(which is proposition 9.3 in Erdmann)

Comment: Yes, because this is done in Erdmann's book, where Theorem 9.4 (this is what we want!) is proved from Theorem 9.3. Note that $tr(xy)=0$ corresponds to $\kappa(x,y)=0$ by applying the adjoint representation.

Comment: Maybe I am making things a little confusing but what I wanted to know, is that how to  modify the proof of Proposition 9.3 so that we get the condition of statement 1 in the question

Comment: Statement 1 is the same as Theorem 9.4., if you rewrite $xy$ as $\operatorname{ad}(x)\operatorname{ad}(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The two statements are just one direction in Cartan's criterion for solvability of $L$. Assuming $tr(xy)=0$ for all $x,y\in L$ is indeed much more than necessary to obtain that $L$ is solvable. It is sufficient to assume that
$tr(xy)=0$ for all $x\in L$, and only for all $y\in [L,L]$, which may be much smaller than $L$. Applying the adjoint representation for an arbitrary Lie algebra gives the version with the Killing form.

For the converse the second statement becomes wrong:
Take $L$ as the $1$-dimensional solvable Lie algebra, the multiples of the unit matrix $I$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$. Then $L$ is abelian, hence solvable. But certainly $tr(xy)=0$ is not true for all $x,y\in L$. So here we see a big difference between the two statements.

Comment: If $x,y \in L$, such that $L\subset gl(V)$, does it mean that $tr(xy)=tr(adx \circ ady)$?

Comment: No, for example ${\rm tr}(ad(x)\circ ad(y))=2n \cdot {\rm tr}(xy)$ for $L=\mathfrak{sl}(n)$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form).